# How can I disable preview for links in skypeforlinux?

Tags: linux-mint, skype

skypeforlinux automatically finds links in a text message and provides these links after sending the message by previewing them. For many links, a preview is created for each individual link. This is annoying and sometimes leads to the message not being sent. At least that's how the client shows it.

How can I stop this behavior?

I am using [Skype version 8.10.0.4 for Linux](https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You used to be able to access this in Tools > Settings on the Windows client, but they removed the ability to specify this. 
Also you can no longer export or save chat messages. 
Seems like they want to dumb things down.